# Passing "this" after brackets in collection .each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So I think that `this` is being passed as a way to be able to maintain the correct reference to `this` which should be to the View. I'm not sure though. Here is the code.

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    getView: function(){
        return this.modelView;
    },
    this.collection.each(function(item){
        var ViewType = this.getModelView(item);
    }, this);
 });
```

So, the last this after the comma is for what? It must be to maintain reference to the correct this but I couldn't find anything that gave a good description of what it was and how it worked. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is the context parameter... `this` inside the `each()` callback will refer to the object passed as the context parameter

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: It's not uncommon that functions that accept a callback also accept an object which is then set as the `this` value of the callback. Most of the time the documentation usually describes whether a function does or not, like in this case. See also [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Ok it makes sense now. Thanks Felix King. After reading through the post you linked to it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

The context of "this" is dynamic in javascript.  This mean "this" means soething different when you are in the each loop.  The way around this propblem

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    var self = this;
    getView: function(){
        return this.modelView;
   },
    this.collection.each(function(item){
        var ViewType = self.getModelView(item);
    }, this);
 });
```

you may need to place the var self = this elsewhere depending on the scope of your function

Comment: Ok so you wouldnt need to pass "this" anymore right? It would work the same without it as long as you had the var self = this; you can just refer to that within your loop.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `this` is passed as second argument, which is what the question was about. The code the OP has works as expected, he wants to know *why*.